# Restarting Cortana without a rebooting Windows

Tags: windows-10, cortana

Cortana has a sleeping problem, it may be narcolepsy. Sometimes I have to wake her up by restarting my computer. Is there a better way to do this?

This is important for me because I rely on **Hey Cortana** in many ways.

Comment: Fix the Cortana in Windows 10, see if it helps  http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/how-fix-start-menu-in-windows-10-3623893/

Comment: @Phoebeli Thanks, noted. Apprehensive because I can't tell if these methods will force me to reteach Cortana.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple and easy.

Just open the task manager and select Cortana and click end task.

Then Cortana should launch again when you type something in the start menu